# Meaning of 伝わる and AよりもB, 温かい, and て-form+から+でも

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

I need help understanding some Japanese sentences. All the sentences are connected except the last one.

> 今も手紙はたまに書きますよ。
>   mailよりも気持ちが伝わるんです。

I know that the first sentence means "people also write letters nowadays".
But it's the second sentence that confuses me. `伝わる` means "to travel" but I guess in this context it means "conveyed/spread".
So does it mean "Feelings can also be conveyed by mail"?.

> 手書きのほうが温かいというか。

Why is `温かい` used here? I thought it meant warm. As in warm water or warm food etc...
Does it mean "Handwritten letters are warm" (as in warm heart)?

and

> あなたの仕事が終わってからでも大丈夫ですよ。

I don't get this one at all. Also, what does `でも` do in the sentence?

Comment: This probably needs to be made at least two, possibly three separate questions.  Since the last sentence is totally unrelated, you could edit that out and make it a separate question.

Comment: mkab, just for reference, *今も手紙はたまに書きますよ。* does not mean "*People also write letters nowadays*" it is more like, "[I] still write letters occasionally you know." (the subject is implied, I picked "I" since it seems like these 3 sentences are from a letter to you -- it could be "people" or something else depending on context).

Comment: @jmac: I get it now. Yeah it was a letter to me.  thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @mkab Please don't ask more than one question per question; the Stack Exchange format doesn't really work if you do that, because you can't vote on individual parts of answers, and because users may not post answers at all unless they want to answer all three questions.

Comment: @snailboat: Ok got it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)

伝わる can have the meaning "to travel" but I think it's easier to remember it as convey. To pass information of emotion to another person.

mailよりも気持ちが伝わるんです。

Let's break this down.

より means "than" or "more than". You seem to have missed this in your translation.

気持ち means feelings

伝わる means convey

んです in this case, is giving a reason as to why she 手紙をたまに書きます。

In not so natural English, "Emotions (feelings) are conveyed more in handwritten letters than email."

2)

Yes. 温かい can also be used in that way. However, there is another kanji: 暖かい. This one can only be used for weather, etc. Not in the way "warm heart".

In the sentence you posted のほうが is showing comparison. We do this in English with "~er" or "more". So here maybe a good translation would be: "You could say handwritten letters are warmer.".

3)

でも in this sense is used as "even". You often see it used like this.

コーヒーでもいかがですか？
How about a coffee or something?

It generally introduces a single option out of many others.

In your case, the option is "after you finish work" but of course, other times would be fine too.

Comment: Wow thanks for the detailed explanation. Yeah I forgot about より and のほうが. They always give me problems. Learnt a lot, especially how でも functions in sentences.  Thanks :)